# libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) (code=1) crash VitamioBundle Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview, vitamio

I'm using VitamioBundle 4.0.1, but I tried all of version of VitamioBundle. It always causes this issue.

My scenarios is start VideoPlayerActivity using VitamioBundle to watch video. From the list related videos in this activity, I select a video to start the second VideoPlayerActivity to watch the second Video. It's ok. But when I press Back to watch the first video, But It destroyed the first VideoPlayerActivity and return to the previous activity. So I can't watch the first Video again. Here is my Logcat:

```
12-25 15:01:59.177: E/MainMenuActivity(17968): onPause()
12-25 15:01:59.197: E/VideoPlayerActivity(17968): onCreate
12-25 15:01:59.307: E/VideoPlayerActivity(17968): onStart
12-25 15:01:59.307: E/Audio focus(17968): 1
12-25 15:01:59.307: E/VideoPlayerActivity(17968): onResume
12-25 15:01:59.587: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): surfaceCreated 0_0
12-25 15:01:59.607: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): surfaceDestroyed 0_0
12-25 15:01:59.607: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): release 0_0
12-25 15:01:59.607: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): end release 0_0
12-25 15:01:59.607: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): surfaceCreated 0_0
12-25 15:01:59.607: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): surfaceChanged 0_0
12-25 15:01:59.607: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): surfaceChanged 0_0
12-25 15:01:59.617: W/ResourceType(17968): Failure getting entry for 0x7f08001d (t=7 e=29) in package 0 (error -75)
12-25 15:02:00.578: I/VitamioPlayer: isNativeLibsInited, APP VERSION: 8, Vitamio Library version: 8
12-25 15:02:00.578: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): PLAY http://tv6.cache24.vcdn.vn/streaming/5f189ca6ea65a24ad21ffb39c1824a7a/52ba9100/2013/1224/cb/15e6eabb6533e4647572104558838c70.mp4?format=f360&device=ios
12-25 15:02:00.578: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): release 0_0
12-25 15:02:00.578: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): end release 0_0
12-25 15:02:00.578: I/VitamioPlayer: LIB ROOT: /data/data/com.vng.zingtv/libs/
12-25 15:02:00.578: I/VitamioPlayer: Copyright (c) YIXIA (http://yixia.com).
12-25 15:02:00.578: I/VitamioPlayer: THIS SOFTWARE (Vitamio) IS WORK OF YIXIA (http://yixia.com)
12-25 15:02:00.578: I/VitamioPlayer: LOAD FFMPEG START: /data/data/com.vng.zingtv/libs/libffmpeg.so
12-25 15:02:00.578: I/VitamioPlayer: LOAD FFMPEG END: /data/data/com.vng.zingtv/libs/libffmpeg.so
12-25 15:02:00.588: I/VitamioPlayer: LOAD VVO START: /data/data/com.vng.zingtv/libs/libvvo.9.so
12-25 15:02:00.588: E/VitamioPlayer: FIND_NAME_SYM vvo, render_yuv
12-25 15:02:00.588: I/VitamioPlayer: LOAD VVO END: /data/data/com.vng.zingtv/libs/libvvo.9.so
12-25 15:02:00.588: I/VitamioPlayer: LOAD VAO START: /data/data/com.vng.zingtv/libs/libvao.0.so
12-25 15:02:00.588: I/VitamioPlayer: LOAD VAO END: /data/data/com.vng.zingtv/libs/libvao.0.so
12-25 15:02:00.588: I/VitamioPlayer: VPLAYER INIT BEGIN
12-25 15:02:00.588: I/VitamioPlayer: Copyright (c) YIXIA (http://yixia.com).
12-25 15:02:00.588: I/VitamioPlayer: THIS SOFTWARE (Vitamio) IS WORK OF YIXIA (http://yixia.com)
12-25 15:02:00.588: I/VitamioPlayer: Application package name: com.vng.zingtv
12-25 15:02:00.598: I/VitamioPlayer: VPLAYER INIT END
12-25 15:02:00.598: I/VitamioPlayer: Copyright (c) YIXIA (http://yixia.com).
12-25 15:02:00.598: I/VitamioPlayer: THIS SOFTWARE (Vitamio) IS WORK OF YIXIA (http://yixia.com)
12-25 15:02:00.598: I/VitamioPlayer: Application package name: com.vng.zingtv
12-25 15:02:00.598: I/VitamioPlayer: Copyright (c) YIXIA (http://yixia.com).
12-25 15:02:00.598: I/VitamioPlayer: THIS SOFTWARE (Vitamio) IS WORK OF YIXIA (http://yixia.com)
12-25 15:02:00.598: I/VitamioPlayer: Application package name: com.vng.zingtv
12-25 15:02:00.608: I/VitamioPlayer: PREPARE SIG: 0
12-25 15:02:00.608: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): end openVideo 1_0
12-25 15:02:00.618: I/VitamioPlayer: THREAD PREPARE START
12-25 15:02:00.618: I/VitamioPlayer: THREAD PREPARE ATTACHED
12-25 15:02:00.618: I/VitamioPlayer: Copyright (c) YIXIA (http://yixia.com).
12-25 15:02:00.618: I/VitamioPlayer: THIS SOFTWARE (Vitamio) IS WORK OF YIXIA (http://yixia.com)
12-25 15:02:00.618: I/VitamioPlayer: OPEN FILE http://tv6.cache24.vcdn.vn/streaming/5f189ca6ea65a24ad21ffb39c1824a7a/52ba9100/2013/1224/cb/15e6eabb6533e4647572104558838c70.mp4?format=f360&device=ios
12-25 15:02:03.531: I/VitamioPlayer: METADATA: isom512isomiso2avc1mp41Lavf54.49.101
12-25 15:02:03.531: I/VitamioPlayer: META AUDIO: 1. und. SoundHandler, META SUBTITLE:
12-25 15:02:03.531: I/VitamioPlayer: WOW: BRILLIANT C COUNT 2
12-25 15:02:03.541: I/VitamioPlayer: OPEN STREAM AUDIO BEGIN
12-25 15:02:03.541: I/VitamioPlayer: Copyright (c) YIXIA (http://yixia.com).
12-25 15:02:03.541: I/VitamioPlayer: THIS SOFTWARE (Vitamio) IS WORK OF YIXIA (http://yixia.com)
12-25 15:02:03.541: I/VitamioPlayer: Application package name: com.vng.zingtv
12-25 15:02:03.541: I/VitamioPlayer: 2, 48000, 0
12-25 15:02:03.571: I/VitamioPlayer: OPEN STREAM AUDIO END
12-25 15:02:03.581: I/VitamioPlayer: Copyright (c) YIXIA (http://yixia.com).
12-25 15:02:03.581: I/VitamioPlayer: THIS SOFTWARE (Vitamio) IS WORK OF YIXIA (http://yixia.com)
12-25 15:02:03.581: I/VitamioPlayer: Application package name: com.vng.zingtv
12-25 15:02:03.581: I/VitamioPlayer: WOW: BRILLIANT C COUNT 2
12-25 15:02:03.581: I/VitamioPlayer: OPEN STREAM VIDEO BEGIN
12-25 15:02:03.581: I/VitamioPlayer: OPEN STREAM VIDEO END
12-25 15:02:03.581: I/VitamioPlayer: THREAD PREPARE DETTACHED
12-25 15:02:03.581: I/VitamioPlayer: THREAD PREPARE END
12-25 15:02:03.581: I/VitamioPlayer: THREAD ANALYTICS START
12-25 15:02:03.581: I/VitamioPlayer: CC: ARMYUV420 0
12-25 15:02:03.621: I/VitamioPlayer: Info (701, 0)
12-25 15:02:03.631: I/VitamioPlayer: Info (901, 0)
12-25 15:02:03.822: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): surfaceChanged 2_3
12-25 15:02:03.952: I/VitamioPlayer: Info (702, 0)
12-25 15:02:04.642: E/VideoPlayerActivity(17968): onPause()
12-25 15:02:04.662: E/VideoPlayerActivity(17968): onCreate
12-25 15:02:04.712: E/VideoPlayerActivity(17968): onStart
12-25 15:02:04.712: E/Audio focus(17968): 1
12-25 15:02:04.712: E/VideoPlayerActivity(17968): onResume
12-25 15:02:04.732: E/VideoInfo(17968): onCreate
12-25 15:02:04.732: E/VideoInfo(17968): onCreateView
12-25 15:02:04.783: E/VideoInfo(17968): onStart
12-25 15:02:04.883: I/VitamioPlayer: THREAD ANALYTICS END
12-25 15:02:05.113: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): surfaceCreated 0_0
12-25 15:02:05.133: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): surfaceDestroyed 0_0
12-25 15:02:05.133: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): release 0_0
12-25 15:02:05.133: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): end release 0_0
12-25 15:02:05.133: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): surfaceCreated 0_0
12-25 15:02:05.143: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): surfaceChanged 0_0
12-25 15:02:05.143: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): surfaceChanged 0_0
12-25 15:02:05.183: W/ResourceType(17968): Failure getting entry for 0x7f08001d (t=7 e=29) in package 0 (error -75)
12-25 15:02:05.373: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): surfaceDestroyed 3_3
12-25 15:02:05.373: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): release 3_3
12-25 15:02:05.373: I/VitamioPlayer: FILE CLOSE BEGIN
12-25 15:02:05.373: I/VitamioPlayer: CLOSE STREAM AUDIO BEGIN
12-25 15:02:05.403: I/VitamioPlayer: CLOSE STREAM AUDIO END
12-25 15:02:05.403: I/VitamioPlayer: CLOSE STREAM VIDEO BEGIN
12-25 15:02:05.403: I/VitamioPlayer: CLOSE STREAM VIDEO END
12-25 15:02:05.413: I/VitamioPlayer: CLOSE AVFORMAT BEGIN
12-25 15:02:05.413: I/VitamioPlayer: CLOSE AVFORMAT END
12-25 15:02:05.413: I/VitamioPlayer: FREE VIDEOPIC BEGIN
12-25 15:02:05.413: I/VitamioPlayer: FREE VIDEOPIC 2 END
12-25 15:02:05.413: I/VitamioPlayer: FREE SUBPIC BEGIN
12-25 15:02:05.413: I/VitamioPlayer: FREE SUBPIC 1 END
12-25 15:02:05.413: I/VitamioPlayer: FREE AUDIOFRAME BEGIN
12-25 15:02:05.413: I/VitamioPlayer: FREE AUDIOFRAME 8 END
12-25 15:02:05.413: I/VitamioPlayer: DELETE GLOBAL REF BEGIN
12-25 15:02:05.413: I/VitamioPlayer: DELETE GLOBAL REF END
12-25 15:02:05.413: I/VitamioPlayer: FILE CLOSE END
12-25 15:02:05.413: I/VitamioPlayer: VPLAYER RELEASE BEGIN
12-25 15:02:05.413: I/VitamioPlayer: VPLAYER RELEASE END
12-25 15:02:05.413: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): end release 0_0
12-25 15:02:05.583: E/VideoPlayerActivity(17968): onStop
12-25 15:02:05.683: I/VitamioPlayer: isNativeLibsInited, APP VERSION: 8, Vitamio Library version: 8
12-25 15:02:05.683: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): PLAY http://tv6.cache24.vcdn.vn/streaming/b14de4ee371248a6a7f5bb08654e6b2b/52ba9105/2013/1211/dd/0860004eb6d6d03295f2410dfd8abfeb.mp4?format=f360&device=ios
12-25 15:02:05.694: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): release 0_0
12-25 15:02:05.694: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): end release 0_0
12-25 15:02:05.694: I/VitamioPlayer: VPLAYER INIT BEGIN
12-25 15:02:05.694: I/VitamioPlayer: Copyright (c) YIXIA (http://yixia.com).
12-25 15:02:05.694: I/VitamioPlayer: THIS SOFTWARE (Vitamio) IS WORK OF YIXIA (http://yixia.com)
12-25 15:02:05.694: I/VitamioPlayer: Application package name: com.vng.zingtv
12-25 15:02:05.694: I/VitamioPlayer: VPLAYER INIT END
12-25 15:02:05.694: I/VitamioPlayer: Copyright (c) YIXIA (http://yixia.com).
12-25 15:02:05.694: I/VitamioPlayer: THIS SOFTWARE (Vitamio) IS WORK OF YIXIA (http://yixia.com)
12-25 15:02:05.694: I/VitamioPlayer: Application package name: com.vng.zingtv
12-25 15:02:05.694: I/VitamioPlayer: Copyright (c) YIXIA (http://yixia.com).
12-25 15:02:05.694: I/VitamioPlayer: THIS SOFTWARE (Vitamio) IS WORK OF YIXIA (http://yixia.com)
12-25 15:02:05.694: I/VitamioPlayer: Application package name: com.vng.zingtv
12-25 15:02:05.694: I/VitamioPlayer: PREPARE SIG: 0
12-25 15:02:05.694: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): end openVideo 1_0
12-25 15:02:05.714: I/VitamioPlayer: THREAD PREPARE START
12-25 15:02:05.714: I/VitamioPlayer: THREAD PREPARE ATTACHED
12-25 15:02:05.714: I/VitamioPlayer: Copyright (c) YIXIA (http://yixia.com).
12-25 15:02:05.714: I/VitamioPlayer: THIS SOFTWARE (Vitamio) IS WORK OF YIXIA (http://yixia.com)
12-25 15:02:05.714: I/VitamioPlayer: OPEN FILE http://tv6.cache24.vcdn.vn/streaming/b14de4ee371248a6a7f5bb08654e6b2b/52ba9105/2013/1211/dd/0860004eb6d6d03295f2410dfd8abfeb.mp4?format=f360&device=ios
12-25 15:02:07.135: I/VitamioPlayer: METADATA: isom512isomiso2avc1mp41Lavf54.49.101
12-25 15:02:07.135: I/VitamioPlayer: META AUDIO: 1. und. SoundHandler, META SUBTITLE:
12-25 15:02:07.135: I/VitamioPlayer: WOW: BRILLIANT C COUNT 2
12-25 15:02:07.145: I/VitamioPlayer: OPEN STREAM AUDIO BEGIN
12-25 15:02:07.145: I/VitamioPlayer: Copyright (c) YIXIA (http://yixia.com).
12-25 15:02:07.145: I/VitamioPlayer: THIS SOFTWARE (Vitamio) IS WORK OF YIXIA (http://yixia.com)
12-25 15:02:07.155: I/VitamioPlayer: Application package name: com.vng.zingtv
12-25 15:02:07.155: I/VitamioPlayer: 2, 48000, 0
12-25 15:02:07.175: I/VitamioPlayer: OPEN STREAM AUDIO END
12-25 15:02:07.175: I/VitamioPlayer: Copyright (c) YIXIA (http://yixia.com).
12-25 15:02:07.175: I/VitamioPlayer: THIS SOFTWARE (Vitamio) IS WORK OF YIXIA (http://yixia.com)
12-25 15:02:07.175: I/VitamioPlayer: Application package name: com.vng.zingtv
12-25 15:02:07.175: I/VitamioPlayer: WOW: BRILLIANT C COUNT 2
12-25 15:02:07.175: I/VitamioPlayer: OPEN STREAM VIDEO BEGIN
12-25 15:02:07.185: I/VitamioPlayer: OPEN STREAM VIDEO END
12-25 15:02:07.185: I/VitamioPlayer: THREAD PREPARE DETTACHED
12-25 15:02:07.185: I/VitamioPlayer: THREAD PREPARE END
12-25 15:02:07.185: I/VitamioPlayer: CC: ARMYUV420 0
12-25 15:02:07.185: I/VitamioPlayer: THREAD ANALYTICS START
12-25 15:02:07.195: I/VitamioPlayer: Info (701, 0)
12-25 15:02:07.205: I/VitamioPlayer: Info (901, 0)
12-25 15:02:07.365: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): surfaceChanged 2_3
12-25 15:02:07.525: I/VitamioPlayer: Info (702, 0)
12-25 15:02:08.507: E/VideoPlayerActivity(17968): onPause()
12-25 15:02:08.517: E/VideoPlayerActivity(17968): onStart
12-25 15:02:08.517: E/Audio focus(17968): 1
12-25 15:02:08.517: E/VideoPlayerActivity(17968): onResume
12-25 15:02:08.527: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): surfaceCreated 0_0
12-25 15:02:08.527: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): release 0_0
12-25 15:02:08.527: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): end release 0_0
12-25 15:02:08.527: I/VitamioPlayer: VPLAYER INIT BEGIN
12-25 15:02:08.527: I/VitamioPlayer: Copyright (c) YIXIA (http://yixia.com).
12-25 15:02:08.527: I/VitamioPlayer: THIS SOFTWARE (Vitamio) IS WORK OF YIXIA (http://yixia.com)
12-25 15:02:08.527: I/VitamioPlayer: Application package name: com.vng.zingtv
12-25 15:02:08.527: I/VitamioPlayer: VPLAYER INIT END
12-25 15:02:08.527: I/VitamioPlayer: Copyright (c) YIXIA (http://yixia.com).
12-25 15:02:08.527: I/VitamioPlayer: THIS SOFTWARE (Vitamio) IS WORK OF YIXIA (http://yixia.com)
12-25 15:02:08.527: I/VitamioPlayer: Application package name: com.vng.zingtv
12-25 15:02:08.527: I/VitamioPlayer: Copyright (c) YIXIA (http://yixia.com).
12-25 15:02:08.527: I/VitamioPlayer: THIS SOFTWARE (Vitamio) IS WORK OF YIXIA (http://yixia.com)
12-25 15:02:08.527: I/VitamioPlayer: Application package name: com.vng.zingtv
12-25 15:02:08.527: I/VitamioPlayer: PREPARE SIG: 0
12-25 15:02:08.537: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): end openVideo 1_0
12-25 15:02:08.537: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): surfaceChanged 1_0
12-25 15:02:08.537: I/VitamioPlayer: THREAD PREPARE START
12-25 15:02:08.537: I/VitamioPlayer: THREAD PREPARE ATTACHED
12-25 15:02:08.537: I/VitamioPlayer: Copyright (c) YIXIA (http://yixia.com).
12-25 15:02:08.537: I/VitamioPlayer: THIS SOFTWARE (Vitamio) IS WORK OF YIXIA (http://yixia.com)
12-25 15:02:08.537: I/VitamioPlayer: OPEN FILE http://tv6.cache24.vcdn.vn/streaming/5f189ca6ea65a24ad21ffb39c1824a7a/52ba9100/2013/1224/cb/15e6eabb6533e4647572104558838c70.mp4?format=f360&device=ios
12-25 15:02:08.607: I/VitamioPlayer: THREAD ANALYTICS END
12-25 15:02:08.647: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): surfaceDestroyed 3_3
12-25 15:02:08.647: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): release 3_3
12-25 15:02:08.647: I/VitamioPlayer: PREPARE HANDLER 12
12-25 15:02:08.647: I/VitamioPlayer: THREAD PREPARE DETTACHED
12-25 15:02:08.647: I/VitamioPlayer: FILE CLOSE BEGIN
12-25 15:02:08.647: I/VitamioPlayer: FREE VIDEOPIC BEGIN
12-25 15:02:08.647: I/VitamioPlayer: FREE VIDEOPIC 2 END
12-25 15:02:08.647: I/VitamioPlayer: FREE SUBPIC BEGIN
12-25 15:02:08.647: I/VitamioPlayer: FREE SUBPIC 1 END
12-25 15:02:08.647: I/VitamioPlayer: FREE AUDIOFRAME BEGIN
12-25 15:02:08.647: I/VitamioPlayer: FREE AUDIOFRAME 8 END
12-25 15:02:08.647: I/VitamioPlayer: DELETE GLOBAL REF BEGIN
12-25 15:02:08.647: I/VitamioPlayer: DELETE GLOBAL REF END
12-25 15:02:08.647: I/VitamioPlayer: FILE CLOSE END
12-25 15:02:08.647: I/VitamioPlayer: VPLAYER RELEASE BEGIN
12-25 15:02:08.647: I/VitamioPlayer: VPLAYER RELEASE END
12-25 15:02:08.647: E/VitamioVideoView(17968): end release 0_0
12-25 15:02:08.657: A/libc(17968): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00002058 (code=1), thread 18198 (com.vng.zingtv)
12-25 15:02:08.707: E/VideoPlayerActivity(17968): onStop
112-25 15:02:08.707: E/VideoPlayerActivity(17968): onDestroy
12-25 15:02:08.877: E/Trace(18212): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-25 15:02:08.947: E/ZingTvApplication(18212): memclass 64
12-25 15:02:08.947: E/CacheManager(18212): usableSpace = 4465856512
12-25 15:02:08.967: W/GAV2(18212): Thread[main,5,main]: Need to call initialize() and be in fallback mode to start dispatch.
12-25 15:02:08.987: E/MainMenuActivity(18212): onCreate()
12-25 15:02:09.077: E/MainMenuActivity(18212): onStart()
```

Does anyone know this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont found this error on Vitamio 4.2.please try.

Comment: I found playing this url http://62.210.89.38:8081/simpsons/simpsons/playlist.m3u8 @CrossleSong